Copy to cliboard msg is not visible
Here is the HTML (with Tailwind included):
<!-- Output Display with Animated Border -->
<div class="relative mb-6 flex items-center overflow-hidden rounded-lg p-[1.8px] border border-gray-300">
  <!-- Animated Border Layer -->
  <div class="animate-rotate absolute inset-0 h-full w-full rounded-lg bg-[conic-gradient(#0e85df_20deg,transparent_120deg)]"></div>

  <!-- Inner Password Output Container -->
  <div class="relative z-20 w-full">
    <input type="text" id="password-output" readonly placeholder="Your Password" class="w-full py-3 px-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg text-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-600 font-semibold font-sans text-xl" />

    <!-- Copy Button -->
    <button id="copy-btn" aria-label="Copy Password" class="absolute right-2 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 16H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h8a2 2 0 012 2v2m-6 12h8a2 2 0 002-2v-8a2 2 0 00-2-2h-8a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2z" />
      </svg>
    </button>

    <!-- Copy Message -->
    <span id="copy-msg" class="absolute left-2 -bottom-6 text-sm text-green-500 hidden opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-500">Copied!</span>
  </div>
</div>            

And JavaScript:
async function copyContent() {
    //this is an api used to copy something on clipboard, it will return promise
    //jo bhi outputtab pr show hoga vo sab dikhega
    

    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(outputTab.value);
        copymsg.classList.remove('hidden');
        copymsg.classList.add('opacity-100');
        copymsg.innerText='Copied!!'
        console.log("copy succesfull")
        
    } catch (error) {
        copymsg.innerText='failed to copy!'
        
    }
    // to make copy span visible
    //this makes any css made in copybtn visible for sometimes
    
    

    //to make copt span hide
    setTimeout(()=>{
        copymsg.classList.add('hidden');
        copymsg.classList.add('hidden');
    },2000);

}

I have invoked the function after this.
I'm expecting to see the copied message but it is not visible, although my code is working but only the message is not visible.

The parent overflow-hidden is clipping anything outside its bounding box. Since the message is positioned outside, it is never visible. Removing the overflow-hidden class makes the copy message visible:


const outputTab = 'Foo';
const copymsg = document.getElementById('copy-msg');

async function copyContent() {
    //this is an api used to copy something on clipboard, it will return promise
    //jo bhi outputtab pr show hoga vo sab dikhega

    try {
        await navigator.clipboard.writeText(outputTab.value);
        copymsg.classList.remove('hidden');
        copymsg.classList.add('opacity-100');
        copymsg.innerText='Copied!!'
        console.log("copy succesfull")
        
    } catch (error) {
        copymsg.innerText='failed to copy!'
        
    }
    // to make copy span visible
    //this makes any css made in copybtn visible for sometimes
    
    

    //to make copt span hide
    setTimeout(()=>{
        copymsg.classList.add('hidden');
        copymsg.classList.add('hidden');
    },2000);

}

document.getElementById('copy-btn').addEventListener('click', copyContent);
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.15"></script>

<!-- Output Display with Animated Border -->
<div class="relative mb-6 flex items-center rounded-lg p-[1.8px] border border-gray-300">
  <!-- Animated Border Layer -->
  <div class="animate-rotate absolute inset-0 h-full w-full rounded-lg bg-[conic-gradient(#0e85df_20deg,transparent_120deg)]"></div>

  <!-- Inner Password Output Container -->
  <div class="relative z-20 w-full">
    <input type="text" id="password-output" readonly placeholder="Your Password" class="w-full py-3 px-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg text-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-red-600 font-semibold font-sans text-xl" />

    <!-- Copy Button -->
    <button id="copy-btn" aria-label="Copy Password" class="absolute right-2 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 hover:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M8 16H6a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h8a2 2 0 012 2v2m-6 12h8a2 2 0 002-2v-8a2 2 0 00-2-2h-8a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2z" />
      </svg>
    </button>

    <!-- Copy Message -->
    <span id="copy-msg" class="absolute left-2 -bottom-6 text-sm text-green-500 hidden opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-500">Copied!</span>
  </div>
</div>            



